# json parse error when posting web app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, package.json

when I am trying to upload my app on heroku it says that parse error: Expected separator between values at line 14, column 16. ! unable to parse package.json

this is how my package.json looks

```js
{
  "name": "ejs-challenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.13"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/text-to-speech": "^4.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you _entirely sure_ that this is what you have committed and deployed? This JSON appears valid and passes an online validator.

Comment: yes, I am getting made I tried everything

Comment: Is there more context to that error message?